# Expressão "n % 2 ? ..." não deveria ser "n % 2 == 1 ? ..."

Tags: javascript

Olá, fiz um exércicio no codewars e uma solução me chamou a atenção:

```
function padIt(str, n) {
  while (n > 0) {
    str = n-- % 2 ? '*' + str : str + '*';
  }
  return str;
}
```

Gostaria de saber, o que exatamente a condição dentro do while faz.

Mais especificamente a condição `n-- % 2 ? ...`, não deveria ser `n-- % 2 == 1 ? ...`

Comment: Se é 1 já é verdadeiro, não precisa da comparação. Veja mais detalhes nos links do quadro amarelo.

Comment: @Bacco muito obrigado! Sinto muito por fazer uma pergunta duplicada, devo apagá-la?

Comment: Duplicatas servem para indexação. Como está positiva, não vejo razão para remover.